# white color appearance at the top of the view

Tags: objective-c, view

In created an app with transparent background but in some of my views white color was shown at the top.
Where as am making view as transparent as

```
self.view.backgroundcolor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

and adding layer like this

```
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame =self.view.frame;
bgLayer.opaque=NO;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

Can any one suggest why I am getting white color at the top of view?

Comment: Do you have any other subviews at the top? Labels?

Comment: yes uibutton  at the top

Comment: then set that button background color to `[UIColor clearColor]` as well

Comment: that color is the background color of widow .

Comment: ? Have u tried what I said?

Comment: yes i have tried that but the problem solved in iphone 6.0 but can see using iphone simulator 5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do go to the xib and see the view hierarchy there and find if you have added some view there by mistake . One another way is in viewDidLoad method add:

```
(UIView * v in self.view.subviews)
{
   NSLog(@"view is %@",[v class]);
}
```

you can get all the added view here .